# How to set HttpOnly flag In Node.js ,Express.js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi I have a project in `node.js` and I want to set the **HttpOnly flag: true** for header response.

I have written the following code in `app.js` but it make no effect in response header .

```
app.use(session({
 secret: "notagoodsecretnoreallydontusethisone",
 resave: false,
 saveUninitialized: true,
 cookie: {httpOnly: true, secure: true}
}));
```

So any suggestion for setting **HttpOnly Flag** in `express.js` is most welcome.

Comment: If you want to set it true, why is your code explicitly setting it to false?

Comment: sorry mistake was there ,i just edited

Comment: I am using this same code but this has no effect ..

Comment: Which version of Express and Express Session middleware are you using?

Comment: both has version of 1.4.28

Comment: Is the cookie being set at all?

Comment: No, i am only using only above line of code.

Comment: What URL are you using to make the request to your express app?

Comment: URL :http://localhost:3000/api/comment of Type POST

Comment: https://localhost:3000/api/comment , ,https

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, are you trying to set the HttpOnly flag for the session cookie, or are you trying to set a custom HTTP header titled httpOnly?

Comment: HttpOnly is something that applies to Cookies. This ensures the cookies cannot be access via JavaScript on the client side. Hope you understand this. When you say "it make no effect in response header", are you referring to the Cookie sent or are you expecting a "httpOnly" header value to be sent back?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you could try this!

```
app.use(session({
   cookieName: 'sessionName',
   secret: "notagoodsecretnoreallydontusethisone",
   resave: false,
   saveUninitialized: true,
   httpOnly: true,  // dont let browser javascript access cookie ever
   secure: true, // only use cookie over https
   ephemeral: true // delete this cookie while browser close
}));
```

Comment: i already got my answer chao,httpOnly works on server when we deploy the code.

Comment: This answer is wrong -- that's how you use sessions but does not answer the actual question of how to set the flag -- sessions don't work on lambda for example.

Answer (score 0):

This example uses cookie-parser library.

Setting a cookie: res.cookie("cookie_name", token, {})

Pass res.cookie() an options object with `httpOnly: true`,

```
 const options = {
    expires: duration,
    httpOnly: true,
  };
```

Final e.g.

```
res.cookie("cookie_name", token, options)
```

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser
- https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html