# How to store JWT token in cookie React fetch

Tags: reactjs, cookies

I am getting token from fetch method in React while I am sending appropriate credentials, but I don't know how to store JWT token in cookie, and later reused it. Below is code block:

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/authenticate/login', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'},
  body: JSON.stringify(loginInfo),
}).then(function (response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(function (json) {
  alert(json.token);
}).catch(function (ex) {
  console.log("parsing failed", ex);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To store a cookie in the browser use

```js
document.cookie=`${cookieName}=${cookieValue};${cookieOptions}`
```

See specs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

If you want to set the cookie from the server, use the `set-cookie` header, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing token in your browser, you should think about how to secure your connection properly.

If that's not the issue, you can store it in `cookies` or `localStorage` for what you will find plenty of tutorials on google. (I like this "[hooks approach](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useCookie.md)" in react)

But to use JWT token properly you should store send it in response as the HttpOnly cookie. See [those implementations](https://owasp.org/www-community/HttpOnly) or [nodeJS implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872956/how-to-set-httponly-flag-in-node-js-express-js-application)

And the browser should attach the token on every new request on it's own. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63228258/can-javascript-react-send-httponly-cookie-to-server)